# How to sort a view on a Drupal Commerce product image field?

Tags: commerce, views

I have several Drupal Commerce views. I want to sort on whether the image is "interesting", which means not equal to `no-image-available.png`.

I have added "Indexed Commerce Product: Image » The image file." as a relationship but it's still not showing up in the sortable fields.

I remember there was something like "enforce" relationship but this is not showing up where I was expecting it:

[image]

Comment: Computed field could be interesting. But I did not try this myself yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to store a sortable value in an extra field.

[Computed field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) can be a good choice. There is a quite lengthy article [here](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field). See "Additional Values for Sorting".

I also want to quote the "Downsides" mentioned in this article:

> Since the stored value computed field is only computed when the node
>   is saved, your nodes need to be re-saved to allow for code changes. If
>   you change the content type’s field, you may need to re-save all nodes
>   of that type. If you have thousands of nodes, this can be troublesome.
>   However, several modules (which are outside the scope of this post)
>   can help, as can simple one-off scripts.